# How to tell on Unity which plugin isn't 64bit compliant?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 64-bit, google-play-console

I am getting the error message below on Google Play Console when I upload a new version of my app.

> "The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices,
>   but they only have 32-bit native code: ..."

My question is: how can I know which library I use isnt 64bit compliant?

Im assuming it's a library that is causing this, as on my project settings I think everything is correct: App Bundle (AAB) is enabled, Scripting backend is IL2CPP, all 3 architectures are checked (ARMv7, ARM64, x86).

And I dont use many libraries, all I use is AdMob, Firebase, Unity Analytics/Diagnostics/IAP and sqlite (which has 3 separate SOs, one tagged for each architecture/CPU).

EDIT: Im using Unity 2019.1.12f1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code Unity Play store error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57621520/apks-or-app-bundles-are-available-to-64-bit-devices-but-they-only-have-32-bit-n)

Try to build your project without the x86 Target Architecture. As x86_64 is not supported by Unity you are missing 64bit on this.

Google describes how to check your libraries for 64 Bit here:  https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

> Does your app include 64-bit libraries?
>   The simplest way to check for 64-bit libraries is to inspect the structure of your APK file. When built, the APK will be packaged with any native libraries needed by the app. Native libraries are stored in various folders based on the ABI. It isn't required to support every 64-bit architecture, but for each native 32-bit architecture you support you must include the corresponding 64-bit architecture.
>
> For the ARM architecture, the 32-bit libraries are located in armeabi-v7a. The 64-bit equivalent is arm64-v8a.
>
> For the x86 architecture, look for x86 for 32-bit and x86_64 for 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Havent tested yet but both answers makes sense (removing x86 and checking the libs on the APK)

Comment: I have just confirmed that removing the x86 build makes the error go away