# APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code Unity Play store error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console

I am trying to build my game for 64 bit architecture as per Google guideline I upgrade the unity to supported LTS version 2018 and change the scripting backend to IL2CPP

[image]

and checked the ARM64 checkbox and using Android application bundles

[image]

but still I am getting error on Google Play console

[image]

I can't understand why I am getting this error as I have followed the google guidelines for 64 bit mention [here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit). How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to build the App without the x86-Architecture.

Otherwise your settings look fine.

Also you can try to export the project (instead of building the app bundle) and build the APK using Android Studio.

Comment: Try to build your project without the x86 Target Architecture. As x86_64 is not supported by Unity you are missing 64bit on this. 
This setting is done in `PlayerSettings` on the Android-Tab. It is the last entry in your first screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I successfully published to Google Play today with Unity 2019.2 after many attempts.

uncheck 86 architecture

uncheck the experimental split apks

export the the project and open in Android Studio

Update everything in Android studio in order for the bundle package (aab) format to work
in Google Play.

create a signed app bundle -> successfully published with no 64-bit requirement error.

Comment: uncheck 86 architecture

Comment: and thats it no need to open in android studio and all that

Comment: @Hamza yes.."Update everything prompted in Android Studio in order for the bundle package (aab) format to work in Google Play".  Then click Build->Create Signed App Bundle. The android studio update was the last thing I changed before a successful Google Play upload.  It makes sense because the message in Android Studio prompting me to update stated it was specifically for improvements to the aab format.