# Error while uploading unity app to Play Store

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have made a game for Android. I have develop and built it in Unity but when I try to distribute the game to the play store I get the following error:

This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 3.

Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app. Learn More

Can someone help with this?

Comment: What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: This question was already asked and answered. [APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code Unity Play store error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57621520/apks-or-app-bundles-are-available-to-64-bit-devices-but-they-only-have-32-bit-n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Player Settings window, under the Other Settings tab, there are checkboxes for what target architectures your app supports. Uncheck the x86 one, if it's there (that depends on your Unity version), and make sure both ARMv7 and ARM64 are checked.

For x86, Unity supports only 32 bits. So if you check that target, the Play Store will complain that no 64 bits version is provided for the x86 platform.

[image: Target Architectures checkboxes]

Comment: to taget arm64 you should build in il2cpp, if this check is disabled switch mono scripting backend to il2cpp